# Estimating difference in implied volatility from difference in PV

Tags: implied-volatility

Le us assume that depo and repo rates are zero. And let us assume I can read the ATM implied volatility of 1y option from the volatility surface. I now have some algorithm to reprice this option (let's say, using local volatility Monte Carlo). Having the PV inferred via Black-Scholes from the ATM implied vol on the vol surface and the PV estimated using local volatility Monte Carlo, I can calculate a difference. Is there a formula to quickly estimate (approximate) what difference in implied vol this difference in PV translates to?

Comment: Yes, implied vol diff= PV diff/ Vega of the option

Comment: @dm63 Ok, that makes sense, but what if I don't know the vega?

Comment: Well you have the (ATM) IV of the option, so you know its Black-Scholes vega.

Comment: @FridoRolloos Yes, it seems this is the answer I was looking for.